# Data listed horizontally or vertically?

Tags: usability, web-app, layout, data, lists

I am currently building a data entry application and a lot of our data is contained in Div's on a page. Right now all of our data is listed horizontally because I feel that it is more readable and is easier to browse for the data. However by doing so we have a lot of white space.

By switching to a two column layout would it make the application more confusing and less usable?

[image: data list]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generally it is easier to work with data that is listed vertically as a list in a single column.

A list is a simpler pattern for the eye to follow, as it is a top to bottom flow.  With two columns, eyes have to follow a z-pattern, which is more tiring.

[image]

Comment: I don't understand what the image is supposed to convey?

Comment: @MarjanVenema They are supposed to show eye movement patterns for various layouts.  I should make that clearer and try find a better example

Comment: @MarjanVenema I hope that is clearer now.

Comment: The answer is correct but the reasoning is just so wrong! The eyes move in a Z-pattern on the screen no matter what. Horizontal listing is bad because of many reasons but this ain't THE reason

Answer (score 2):

found this great article to answer my question http://baymard.com/blog/avoid-multi-column-forms

Comment: You beat me to the article :)  At least that is where I got my image from.